# "I have bought it" versus "I have it bought"

Tags: word-order, causatives, causative-have

1. I have bought it (Present Perfect)
2. I have it bought. (Present Simple ??)

What's the difference in the meaning between these two sentences?

Comment: I don't think that #2 is an "inversion" of Present Perfect. I suggest "bought" in #2 functions as a sort of "complement", indicating the state of the object "it" in the context of the Simple Present verb ***have***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two sentences have completely different meanings and structures.

The first sentence is the present perfect and means I bought something in the past, and this purchase has a present result, likely that I now own that thing.

The second sentence is in the *present simple* form and uses *passive causative with "have"*. It roughly means *I regularly cause someone to buy it*, likely by asking them or paying them.

> Alice: Do you go out and buy the newspaper yourself every morning?
> Bob: No, I have it bought.

The general structure is *[ "have" + object + past participle ]*

Here are some examples with different tenses:

> I have the house painted every year. (*present simple*)
> I have had the house painted. (*present perfect*)
> I had the house painted. (*simple past*)
> I am having the house painted. (*present continuous*)

Answer (score -1):

The simple present would be, "I buy it."

"I have bought it" is present perfect. This indicates action over a period of time. Like you might say, "I have bought bread", meaning that you bought bread many times over a period of time.

"Have " is also used for an emphatic past tense. Like, "Did you buy it?" "Yes, I have bought it."

"I have it bought" is an unlikely thing for a fluent English speaker to say. Yes, it's grammatically correct. By changing the word order from the standard, you put emphasis on "it" rather than "bought". You might say this if the means of acquiring "it" is unimportant, like you might have bought it, or you might have gotten it as a gift or stolen it or whatever, but the important thing is that you now have it. Or if the "it" is particularly important. Like you are trying to emphasize that you have "it" -- whatever "it" is -- and not some other thing of less value or interest. But all that said, a fluent speaker would be unlikely to say this.

Comment: "I have it bought for me" would mean "I get someone else to buy it for me" .

Comment: @KateBunting Could you please share more examples with "it" before "bought"?

Comment: No, because I can't think of any other context in which "I have it bought" would make sense in current English.

Comment: @KateBunting Please just use any other verbs

Comment: "I have it [participle]" isn't a tense.  It could mean (A) that you employ someone to do something for you - "Your hair looks nice." "Thanks - I have it cut by Pierre" - or (B) that you are presenting an item to which you have done something - "Where's my best shirt?" - "I have it washed and ironed for you."

Comment: -1 "I have it bought" *is* present simple. It just also has another structure as well. In present perfect, it would be, "*I **have had** it bought*"

Comment: "I have it" is simple present. "I have it bought" is ... something else, not any commonly used wording for verb tenses in English.